# Get user Active Directory location without Get-ADUser?

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to get the current users AD location property without using Get-ADUser?

Even better would be without connecting to AD at all, if it is cached locally somewhere?

I have a login script that I'm trying to base some logic on the current users AD location however I'm stuck trying to read it!

I'm looking into [System.DirectoryServices] but I can't seem to find an easy way to just directly access the current users properties without having to actively search AD for the user.

I wanted to keep this as slim as possible for speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result I went with was:

```
$user = (([adsisearcher]"samaccountname=$env:username").FindOne()).properties
$user.physicaldeliveryofficename
```

However it would still be good if there was some way to get this detail without querying AD.